# Choosing Truecrypt volume names and keyfile names

Tags: encryption, truecrypt

Any recommendations on what to name Truecrypt volumes (container files) and where to locate them?  Certainly a name like "this is a truecrypt volume.tc" isn't a good idea.  Any recommended storage locations?

Same question for keyfiles that are generated with Truecrypt.

Finally, lets say you choose an existing file, ymca.mp3, as your keyfile.  Given that that file is innocuous and normal looking, isn't it easy to forget that's your key file so when you get sick of the Village People and delete the song you're hosed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it need an obfuscated filename if it is encrypted?

Can you elaborate on 'Any recommended storage locations?'.  Surely depends on what you want to do with the file(s).  I have my truecrypt container on Dropbox so it is available everywhere I have truecrypt.

For you last question, I guess it's just a case of being careful.  Choose files that are unlikely to be removed by accident but at the same time don't choose files that will possibly change in the future, such as system files.

Comment: Good point about the obfuscated filename.  My initial thought on this was to hide the presence of a Truecrypt volume but this makes no sense anyway since it's obvious that TC is installed.